# Using xdg-open odt files

Tags: linux, rhel

I am writing a document database using perlTk. Upon double clicking the selected file on my GUI I use xdg-open to use the default application to open the file. I am having some issues opening .odt files (openoffice I think) `xdg-open Add_new_user.odt` returns the error

`gvfs-open: file:///misc/croc_common/computing/notes/Add_new_user.odt: error launching application: Failed to execute child process "openoffice.org3" (No such file or directory)`

The command openoffice.org (no 3) on my system will open libreoffice.

When I enter `xdg-mime query filetype Add_new_user.odt` on the command line I get the following message which I do not understand
`application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text`

How do I fix this issue? I am using redhat 6.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to re-assign default application for `application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text` :

```
xdg-mime default libreoffice-writer.desktop "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text"
```

Comment: I get the error `xdg-mime: malformed argument 'libreoffice', expected *.desktop`. When I add .desktop the error changes to `/usr/bin/xdg-mime: line 531: kde-config: command not found; mkdir: cannot create directory `': No such file or directory; /usr/bin/xdg-mime: line 542: /profilerc.new: Permission denied` - I'm using gnome. Prefixing `sudo` to the command also does not help

Comment: It's weird. Try simply to change default file inside your `gnome` file manager. Or see explainations [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Default_Applications)

Comment: @ both: There is no such file as `libreoffice.desktop` on any platform. The launcher is called `libreoffice-writer.desktop` so setting that as default for `.odt` files via `gvfs-mime set` or `xdg-mime default` should work.